# Shaders vs renderers: Photorealism

Tags: shaders, rendering, terminology

What is Renderer? How it is different from a shader?

For Photorealism which one is more important?

Comment: This post appears to be two distinct questions. Please only include one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Shaders and renderers are two different things. A renderer is simply a piece of code written on top of a rendering API (such as OpenGL or DirectX) and it handles the model rendering (hence the name).

A shader is also a piece of code, but it runs on the GPU. It's optimized to work on hundreds of threads at once and it's usually used to figure out the position of a vertex (a point of a 3d model) relative to the camera (vertex shader) or to figure out the color of a certain pixel (fragment shader).

Your third question makes no sense currently. None of them are required to achieve photorealism. You can make photorealistic images with just shaders (like [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/)) and you can also achieve it without using a shader, in fact, ray tracing is the current standard in movie making and it doesn't have to involve the usage of shaders.

Comment: I would argue that even the ShaderToy example has a very simple renderer in play, providing the viewport and quad geometry with UV coordinates to be shaded, and piping in variables like texture sources or user input. ;) And a raytracing renderer is still a renderer, it's just a fundamentally different way of implementing responsibility for generating an image.

Comment: @DMGregory 1.) Fair point 2.) Thanks for mentioning, that should've been the renderer only one, I'll fix it